# How to add a (mouse)event to a XMLDocument of a SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to add a picture of a car to my webpage, and I want to pop up some information about the car when hovering with the mouse over the image. I am using D3.

```
d3.xml("images/car.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(error, xml) {
  if (error) throw error;
  xml.documentElement.id = 'car';
  xml.documentElement.childNodes[1].style = 'fill:'+ col_carbondioxide +'; width: 30%';
  xml.documentElement.setAttribute("height", pic_height);
  document.getElementById('introduction').appendChild(xml.documentElement);
});
```

How do I add an event listener for e.g. a mouse over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to listen [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) events:

```js
var col_carbondioxide = 'red';
var pic_height = 200;
var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Orange_sport_car.svg';
var container = document.getElementById('introduction');

d3.xml(url, 'image/svg+xml', function(xml) {
  if (xml && xml.documentElement) {
    xml.documentElement.id = 'car';
    xml.documentElement.childNodes[1].style = 'fill:'+ col_carbondioxide +'; width: 30%';
    xml.documentElement.setAttribute('height', pic_height);
    var car = container.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
    car.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      console.log('Show some information about the car.');
    }, false);
    car.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      console.log('Hide some information about the car.');
    }, false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="introduction"></div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an `addEventListener` like this :

```
document.getElementById("car").addEventListener('mouseover', whenMouseOver, false);

function whenMouseOver() {
    console.log("Mouse over !");
}
```

Since `SVG` is just XML and can be use inside HTML, you only have to use the right `id` for the right element.

Comment: Works, but I was trying to avoid getting the element back from the page after I just appended it. Valentin's answer was exactly what I needed. Thanks anyways!